# Samsung GT-I9060 have white screen issue on startup app

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic2, ionic-native

I am using the fresh ionic blank project and it's provide me white screen after splash screen and nothing happens after that
     when i try to check logs ionic cordova run android -lc
    Getting this error
    The connection to server was unsuccessful (http://192.168.0.8:8100)

I try with ionic cordova run android --prod all kind of slug but not effect 
        and i am using blank new

```
project
  variables.scss
   $colors: (
       primary: #488aff,
       secondary: #32db64,
      danger: #f53d3d,
      light: #f4f4f4,
      dark: #222
       );
   config.xml
```

> preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" 
>   preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"
>   preference
>    name="SplashScreen" value="screen"
>   preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"

I don't want to use crosswalk into my app

```
: 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
local packages:
: 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node : v6.11.0
npm : 3.10.10
OS : Windows 8.1
Environment Variables:
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
Misc:
backend : legacy
```

Comment: is the device connected to the same WIFI network as the laptop/desktop?

Comment: no desktop connected with LAN and mobile connected with mobile data connection

Comment: When using livereload you have to connect your phone to the same network as your computer that serves - where `ionic serve/run` is running.

Comment: Ionic version 2 supports Android 4.4+ but i have 4.2.2 how fixed this problem any idea

Comment: I'm afraid that using Crosswalk would be the only way to fix that since Ionic won't work on Android 4.2.2 without it.

Comment: my app size is 4.12 mb that us  lite version if i added Crosswalk app have 19 mb that is huge number can i upload multiple apk for different  api level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163631/discussion-between-manoj-bhardwaj-and-sebaferreras).